# Sending relation to UDF functions

Tags: apache-pig

Can I Send a relation to Pig UDF function as input? A relation can have multiple tuples in it. How do we read each tuple one by one in Pig UDF function?

Ok.Below is my Sample input file.

```
Surender,HDFC,60000,CTS
Raja,AXIS,80000,TCS
Raj,HDFC,70000,TCS
Kumar,AXIS,70000,CTS
Remya,AXIS,40000,CTS
Arun,SBI,30000,TCS
Vimal,SBI,10000,TCS
Ankur,HDFC,80000,CTS
Karthic,HDFC,95000,CTS
Sandhya,AXIS,60000,CTS  
Amit,SBI,70000,CTS

myinput = LOAD '/home/cloudera/surender/laurela/balance.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS(name:chararray,bank:chararray,amt:long,company:chararray);

grouped = GROUP myinput BY company;
```

All i need is details  about highest paid  employee in each company. How do i use UDF for that ?

I need something like this

```
CTS     Karthic,HDFC,95000,CTS
TCS     Raja,AXIS,80000,TCS
```

Can SomeOne Help me on this.

Comment: You can send a bag to a UDF, which is the same thing. But why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script will give you the results you want :

```
    A = LOAD '/home/cloudera/surender/laurela/balance.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS(name:chararray,bank:chararray,amt:long,company:chararray);

    B = GROUP A BY (company);
    topResults = FOREACH B {result = TOP(1, 2, A); GENERATE FLATTEN(result);}
    dump topResults;
```

### Explanation:

First we group A on the basis of company.So A is:

(CTS,{(Surender,HDFC,60000,CTS),(Kumar,AXIS,70000,CTS),(Remya,AXIS,40000,CTS),(Ankur,HDFC,80000,CTS),(Karthic,HDFC,95000,CTS),(Sandhya,AXIS,60000,CTS),(Amit,SBI,70000,CTS)})

(TCS,{(Raja,AXIS,80000,TCS),(Raj,HDFC,70000,TCS),(Arun,SBI,30000,TCS),(Vimal,SBI,10000,TCS)})

Then we say foreach tuple in B , generate another tuple **result** which is equal to the **top 1** record from the relation **A** found in B on the basis of value of column number 2 i.e. amt. The columns are numbered from 0.

**Note**
First your data has extra spaces after company name. Please remove the extra spaces or use the following data :

```
  Surender,HDFC,60000,CTS
  Raja,AXIS,80000,TCS
  Raj,HDFC,70000,TCS
  Kumar,AXIS,70000,CTS
  Remya,AXIS,40000,CTS
  Arun,SBI,30000,TCS
  Vimal,SBI,10000,TCS
  Ankur,HDFC,80000,CTS
  Karthic,HDFC,95000,CTS
  Sandhya,AXIS,60000,CTS
  mit,SBI,70000,CTS
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks Much.. I would also like to know how do we do get the same output with the help of UDF. Basically i want to send the entire single relation to UDF function and read each tuple in that relation and apply some logic.Pls help

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write an UDF to do this, you can simply do it with the top function from pig : http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/func.html#topx

Here is an example of code that should work ( not tested) :

```
grouped = GROUP myinput BY company;
result = FOREACH grouped GENERATE company, FLATTEN(TOP(1,2,grouped));
```